# Read/Write IFF and make changes

Tags: java

How I read the file IFF raster graphics, and make changes to it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the [Java Imaging Utilities](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jiu/) library has a built-in codec for it. I've never used it myself, but I did download it and look through the manual; it looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for the ILBM file format, once very popular on the Amiga platform.
I found the this [article](http://www.fine-view.com/jp/labs/doc/ilbm.txt) and the same in html [here](http://home.comcast.net/~erniew/lwsdk/docs/filefmts/ilbm.html) written by Jerry Morrison @ Electronic Arts.

If you are just looking in to converting old pictures to lets say ping format to be used in your java app, you can use GraphicsConverter for Mac.

Good luck!